# How to properly show QIcon on a QTreeWidget child?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I successfully managed to show a `QIcon` on the `TopLevelItem`.
But the problem comes when to add the icon on the children, how do I do that?

Below a snippet from the example I am building:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTreeWidgetItem *top1 = new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Images" });
    QTreeWidgetItem *top2 = new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Path" });
    QTreeWidgetItem *top3 = new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Segmentation" });

    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> children1;
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> children2;
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> children3;

    children1.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Original" }));
    children1.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Sample" }));
    children1.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Black/White" }));

    children2.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Left Side" }));
    children2.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Right Side" }));
    children2.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Center Side" }));

    children3.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Edge Detection" }));
    children3.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Clustering" }));
    children3.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Region-Based" }));
    children3.append(new QTreeWidgetItem({ "Mask RNN" }));

    top1->addChildren(children1);
    top1->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
    top2->addChildren(children2);
    top2->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
    top3->addChildren(children3);
    top3->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));

    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2, top3 });

}
```

What I have done so far:

I went through the following [post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31161-TreeWidget-child-icon) which helped me with managing the icon for the `TopLevelItem` but when I tried to do the same for the children I didn't have the same luck.

I used a `QList` to take care of all the children in the following way :

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> children1;
```

I am now wondering if that could be a good way to proceed since no icon where added.
Of course I tried the following but didn't work:

```
children1->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
```

Because `setIcon` is not a member function among the choices and am wondering if there is a more detailed procedure to do that.

I also used [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69785-Adding-Icons-to-QTreeView-QAbstractItemModel), [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41897-adding-elements-to-QTreeWidget-column-2) but none of them was useful to do that.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: Does `children1[0]->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));` work?

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading the question! :) Unfortunately your suggestion does not work. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to your question

To access the children of an item you need to use [`QTreeWidgetItem::child`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#child):

```
top1->child(0)->setIcon(0, QIcon("/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
```

### Proper solution

That being said, I would approach the problem in another way.

I would create a helper function, e.g.:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath)
{
    auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(name);

    item->setIcon(0, QIcon(iconPath));

    return item;
}
```

Then I would use it like that:

```
top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
...
```

And there is no need to keep a list with the children, as they are accissible through the `child` method.

### Example

Here is how to apply the proposed solution in your case:

```
auto *top1 = createItem("Images", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png");
auto *top2 = createItem("Path", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png");
auto *top2 = createItem("Segmentation", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png");

top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top1->addChild(createItem("Black/White", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));

top2->addChild(createItem("Left Side", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top2->addChild(createItem("Right Side", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top2->addChild(createItem("Center Side", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));

top3->addChild(createItem("Edge Detection", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top3->addChild(createItem("Clustering", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top3->addChild(createItem("Region-Based", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));
top3->addChild(createItem("Mask RNN", "/home/ultrasound_mapper/laserscan.png"));

ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2, top3 });
```

As you see, the code has become cleaner and more maintainable.

**Note:** Of course you could put the correct images. However, if you indend to use only one image, then you can omit the `iconPath` parameter and set a fixed image as an icon.

Comment: :) Yes that works! Thanks for stopping by and reading the question! Very much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Emanuele, you are very welcome! Btw., you might as well read the addition to my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @Emanuele, I've also added an example of how to use the proposed solution in your case.

Comment: The helper function you proposed is a great idea!!! And your additional explanations made it super clear! Thank you very much for your time and have a great weekend!! :) :)

Comment: @Emanuele, I am glad you like it! Have a great weekend too!